# magnific-popup generates "file not found" error for YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am trying to make a popup containing a YouTube video.  The code I have is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vid1').magnificPopup({
    items:{
      src: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O2aH4XLbto'
    },
    type:'iframe'
  });
});
```

I get a popup that says `The file or directory could not be found.`  What am I missing or doing wrong?  I have tried multiple types of YouTube links; all result in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to view the video from a local file? YouTube player blocks that. (file:///) You have to test their videos from a web server. (http(s)://)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason u cant load youtube or vimeo video from localhost,use a code editor like [brackets](http://brackets.io/) it has a built in server.You can see your video working if u use the "live preview".

Answer (score 0):

Put `type:'iframe'` inside the items object.

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vid1').magnificPopup({
    items:{
      src: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O2aH4XLbto',
      type:'iframe'
    },

  });
});
```

Comment: Yes. "GET file://www.youtube.com/embed/0O2aH4XLbto?autoplay=1 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: Are you check it in other browser

Comment: Yes in other browsers I get a similar message. "File not found

Firefox can't find the file at /embed/0O2aH4XLbto?autoplay=1.

    Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted."  magnificpopup is changing the url which doesn't work.